# Asterisk get_variable, in Perl AGI

Tags: perl, asterisk

I am little new to Asterisk AGI. I am using perl with asterisk agi.

I need to design an IVR solution using Perl asterisk agi.

I have write a little code and it is executing fine.

### Perl Code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
  use Asterisk::AGI;
  my $agi = new Asterisk::AGI;
  my $option1 = "";
  my $option2 = "";

$agi->exec("Read","option1,recording-201503252343,1,,,");
$option2 = $agi->get_variable("$option1");
$agi->exec("NoOp","$option1");

if($option2 == 1)
{
  $agi->exec("Playback","hello-world");
  $agi->exec("Goto","English,s,1");
}
```

---

### Asterisk Dialplan:-

```
exten => 12345,1,Answer()
exten => 12345,2,AGI(agi_new-new.pl)
exten => 12345,n,NoOP(${AGISTATUS})
exten => 12345,n,Hangup()
```

---

Actually what i did in the code is that i want a user to dial the extension lead by the IVR in which 2 options are prompted and he has to choose between 2 options when he/she enter the options i want to store that digit into a variable so that i use condition on that variable.
I use get_variable to get the variable but when i press the desired option it gets that dtmf input but it is not storing in the variable via the command get_variable.

please i need little help on this.

if anyone could help it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about asterisk, but Perl interpolates variables in double quotes. Hence, `"$option"` is the same `'' . $option` - maybe you want `'$option'` instead? Single quotes don't interpolate.

Comment: dear still having same output. it not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$AGI->get_variable()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Asterisk::AGI#AGI-get_variable-variable) gets variable stored in channel data. Catched DTMF digits don't stored in the data of current channel. For your case you need use
[$AGI->get_data()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Asterisk::AGI#AGI-get_data-filename-timeout-maxdigits).

```
# Wait 3 seconds for press button
my $option1 = $agi->get_data('recording-201503252343',3000,1);
if ($option1 == 1) {
  # do something
}
```

And in your example you have errors. Defined `$option1` is empty. You executing command `Read` with catching DTMF in `option1` and next you want get value of `$option1` (empty). Either it's a typo in the example in the `Read` command (`option1` instead of `$option1`) or it is a wrong code, which works as expected.

Comment: ohhhhhhh GOD!.. Really appreciate your answer bro.. its work for me.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: ok can you please give me some example code with get_variable and Read because they are still not working for me or either i don't know how to use them.
I am really thankful to you.

Comment: I never used  `get_variable` for `Read`. Cannot help with sample code.

Comment: ok.. so for what we use get_variable.. I saw lot of example codes and they used the get_variable followed by the read.

       ' $AGI->exec("Read","\option,custom/inquiry-tocheck,1,,,\"");
        $option = $AGI->get_variable(option); '