# Unable to catch return value of Asterisk::AGI get_variable

Tags: perl, agi

I have a *1.agi* file that sets asterisk variable by using following code

```
$AGI->set_variable("MY_CALLID",$value);
```

I am using following lines of code in *2.agi* to retrieve that value (Value here is 20)

```
my $MY_CALLID = $AGI->get_variable('MY_CALLID');
$LOG->debug($AGI->get_variable('MY_CALLID'));
```

In console I can see that the value is returned by asterisk. But the variable could not catch it. See log below (I am using Log::Log4perl)

```
<SIP/tufli-0000000d>AGI Rx << GET VARIABLE MY_CALLID
<SIP/tufli-0000000d>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1 (20)
<SIP/tufli-0000000d>AGI Rx << GET VARIABLE MY_CALLID
<SIP/tufli-0000000d>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1 (20)
Warning: Log message argument #1 undefined at /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/xxx/2.agi line 35
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Appender.pm line 177, <STDIN> line 23.
Warning: Log message argument #1 undefined at /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/xxx/2.agi line 35
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Log/Log4perl/Appender.pm line 177, <STDIN> line 23.
<SIP/tufli-0000000d>AGI Rx << 2016-06-15 15:59:40.983 | DEBUG | at /var/li | main                :35    |
```

What did I miss?!

Just as some additional info, I'm using

```
$| = 1;
```

at beginning of my scripts (just a doubt if it has to do anything with this).

I saw a similar question [here @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509316/asterisk-get-variable-in-perl-agi) but it is regarding user input not asterisk variable.

Comment: It's not because of context. From [the source](https://metacpan.org/source/JAMESGOL/asterisk-perl-1.03/lib/Asterisk/AGI.pm#L557) it looks like it should work the way you are using it.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, but it doesn't.